# How to register Generic type with Unity container

Tags: generics, dependency-injection, unity-container, repository-pattern

I am struggling to inject a generic type repository into my service class using Unity. At lease, I think this generic repository is what is causing the trouble.  Can somebody please point out what am I doing wrong?. Please bear with me since I am fairly new to Unity.  Firstly, here is the error message I receive the following error.

Resolution of the dependency failed, type = "TestUnity.Services.Contracts.ICustBillingTypeService", name = "(none)".
Exception occurred while: while resolving.

### Exception is: InvalidOperationException - The type String cannot be constructed. You must configure the container to supply this value.

At the time of the exception, the container was:

Resolving TestUnity.Services.Implementations.CustBillingTypeService,(none) (mapped from TestUnity.Services.Contracts.ICustBillingTypeService, (none))
  Resolving parameter "repo" of constructor TestUnity.Services.Implementations.CustBillingTypeService(TestUnity.Repositories.Contracts.IRepository`1[[TestUnity.DAL.CustBillingType, TestUnity.DAL, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]] repo)
    Resolving TestUnity.Repositories.Implementations.Repository`1[TestUnity.DAL.CustBillingType],(none) (mapped from TestUnity.Repositories.Contracts.IRepository`1[TestUnity.DAL.CustBillingType], (none))
    Resolving parameter "ctx" of constructor TestUnity.Repositories.Implementations.Repository`1[[TestUnity.DAL.CustBillingType, TestUnity.DAL, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]](TestUnity.Repositories.Contracts.IDataContext ctx)
      Resolving TestUnity.Repositories.Implementations.DataContext,(none) (mapped from TestUnity.Repositories.Contracts.IDataContext, (none))
      Resolving parameter "nameOrConnectionString" of constructor TestUnity.Repositories.Implementations.DataContext(System.String nameOrConnectionString)
        Resolving System.String,(none)

Here is my Unity bootstrap class that is in a separate class library

```
    public static class UnityBootstrap
{
    private static IUnityContainer container;
    public static IUnityContainer Container
    {
        get
        {
            if (container == null)
                InitializeContainer();
            return container;
        }
    }

    public static void InitializeContainer()
    {
        container = new UnityContainer();
        container.RegisterType<ICustBillingTypeService, CustBillingTypeService>();
        container.RegisterType<IDataContext, DataContext>();
        container.RegisterType(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(Repository<>));
    }
}

    public interface IRepository<T> where T : class, IObjectState
{
    T FindOne(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
}

    public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class, IObjectState
{
    private readonly IDataContext context;
    private readonly IDbSet<T> dbSet;

    public Repository() { }

    public Repository(IDataContext ctx)
    {
        this.context = ctx;
        var dbContext = context as DbContext;
        dbSet = dbContext.Set<T>();
    }

    public virtual T FindOne(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return dbSet.SingleOrDefault(predicate);
    }
}

public interface ICustBillingTypeService
{
    CustBillingType GetCustBillingTypeByPKId(int pkId);
}

public class CustBillingTypeService : ICustBillingTypeService
{
    IRepository<CustBillingType> custBillingTypeRepo;

    public CustBillingTypeService() { }

    public CustBillingTypeService(IRepository<CustBillingType> repo)
    {
        custBillingTypeRepo = repo;
    }
    public CustBillingType GetCustBillingTypeByPKId(int pkId)
    {
        var cbt = custBillingTypeRepo.FindOne(x => x.PKId == pkId);
        return cbt;
    }
}

public interface IDataContext : IDisposable
{
    int SaveChanges();
    void SyncObjectState<TEntity>(TEntity entity) where TEntity : class, IObjectState;
    void SyncObjectsStatePostCommit();
}


public class DataContext : DbContext, IDataContext
{
    private readonly Guid _instanceId;
    bool _disposed;

    public DataContext(string nameOrConnectionString) : base(nameOrConnectionString)
    {
        _instanceId = Guid.NewGuid();
        Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    }
    public Guid InstanceId { get { return _instanceId; } }
    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        SyncObjectsStatePreCommit();
        var changes = base.SaveChanges();
        SyncObjectsStatePostCommit();
        return changes;
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!_disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
            }
            _disposed = true;
        }

        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}

public partial class TestModel : DataContext
{
    public TestModel() : base("name=TestModel") {}

    public virtual DbSet<CustBillingType> CustBillingTypes { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        CustBillingTypeModelBuilder.Map(modelBuilder);
    }
}

[TestClass]
public class UnityTestCases
{
    private IUnityContainer uContainer;
    private ICustBillingTypeService icbService;
    public UnityTestCases()
    {
        uContainer = UnityBootstrap.Container;
        icbService = uContainer.Resolve<ICustBillingTypeService>();
    }
    [TestMethod]
    public void GetCustBillingTypeByPKId_return_ValidObj()
    {
        var obj = icbService.GetCustBillingTypeByPKId(pkId: 15);
        Assert.IsNotNull(obj);
    }
}
```

Please note that in my test case, I am not mocking anything.  This is sort of integration test.

If I had to guess, I would think there is something wrong with the Generic Type Registration.  Or it could be totally something else.

Babu.

Comment: Do you want to use `DataContext` or `TestModel`? If you want to use `DataContext` directly, which connection string/name do you want to use?

Comment: Yacoub: TestModel is the DbContext created by Entity Framework.  I am applying DataContext which inherits from DbContext and implements IDataContext.  So, do I need to resolve DataContext to TestModel and if so, I would greatly appreciate some sample code.  Thanks.

Comment: You are registering `IDataContext` to `DataContext`  (`container.RegisterType<IDataContext, DataContext>();`). If you want to use `TestModel` instead, you should specify this in the registration. I.e., replace the above registration with this: `container.RegisterType<IDataContext, TestModel>();`

Comment: Yacoub: Thanks so much.  That did it!  Stupid of me!!  If you can post the solution as your answer, I will mark it accepted.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mapping `IDataContext` to `DataContext` like this:

```
container.RegisterType<IDataContext, DataContext>();
```

`DataContext` constructor needs a connection string/name as an argument which you are not supplying.

Either supply this value like this:

```
container.RegisterType<IDataContext, DataContext>(
    new InjectionConstructor("name=TestModel"));
```

Or use the `TestModel` instead of the `DataContext`. This is what you intended to do, I guess. `TestModel` already has a default constructor so you don't need to supply the connection string:

```
container.RegisterType<IDataContext, TestModel>();
```

IMO, it makes sense to have the connection string visible in the [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/) (which in your example is the `UnityBootstrap` class), and not have it hard coded in the default constructor of `TestModel`. The connection string is basically a [primitive dependency](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/07/02/PrimitiveDependencies/) that you might want to change in the future.

Comment: Yacoub: It worked when I replaced DataContext with TestModel.  But I guess, you have a good point that connectionstring is better off injected into the context.  I do expect the connection string to change in the future.  So, I tried your first suggestion.  But now, I get an error saysing "The entity type CustBillingType is not part of the model for the current context".  Any idea?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Create a constructor in `TestModel` that accepts a connection string/name, and then map `IDataContext` to `TestModel` and use `InjectionConstructor` to specify the connection string.

Comment: Yacoub:  Thanks for your prompt replies.  I will give it a try.  But the way I tried with your earlier suggestion is: `container.RegisterType<IDataContext, DataContext>( new InjectionConstructor("name=TestModel"));`.  That is when I got the aforementioned error message.  Registering this way on the base context seems more elegant to me.

Comment: You have to use `TestModel` because you need a `DbSet` for `CustBillingType`.